# List.\\ don't removes empty lists in a list of lists

Tags: list, haskell

I am facing something very strange:

these lines of code:

```
piles n =
  let
    listes2 = map (\i -> [n-i,i]) [1..(n `div` 2)]
  in ( [[n,0]] ++ (L.concat [trouveTous [l] | l <- listes2 ])) L.\\ []
```

produces a list of lists where there are some [].
due to the "L.\ []" just before the return of the function "listes", how can [] be present in the return?

Comment: The `(//)` operator only removes the *first* occurrence of an item. Try using `filter` instead.

Comment: thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `xs \\ ys` removes the first occurrence of an element in `ys` from `xs`, e.g.

```
[1,2,1,2] \\ [1] == [2,1,2]
```

Furthermore, `[]` doesn't contain an element at all, so `\\ []` doesn't have any effect:

```
xs \\ [] = xs -- due to (ys ++ xs) \\ ys == xs and [] ++ xs == xs
```

However, you can use `filter` if you want to remove a empty lists from a list of lists:

```
filter (not . null) [[1,2,3,5], [], [1,2,3], [], [1,2]] == [[1,2,3,5], [1,2,3], [1,2]]
```